# Windows: Look up screen resolution when running as a service

Tags: windows, winapi

I have code running as a Windows service which would like to determine the resolution of the directly attached monitors.

(Yes, I appreciate that the user may be interacting with the machine via RDP, VDI etc., so this doesn't always make sense - but this is just an optimisation, so in the common case where there is a single directly-attached desktop, it would still be useful.)

I'd like to use `::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN)` but it returns 0, as I'm running in session 0. Similarly `EnumDisplayDevices` looks like it will only work for the present interactive session.

We'd like to be able to do this even when no user is logged in.

Is there a way to explore hardware screen resolutions even as a service?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162609.aspx) for `EnumDisplayDevices()` clearly says:

> The EnumDisplayDevices function lets you obtain information about the display devices **in the current session**.

Since a service runs in session 0, and there are no displays in session 0, there is no monitor information for it to enumerate.

Try using [`EnumDisplayMonitors()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162610.aspx) instead.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I suspect `EnumDisplayMonitors()` suffers from the same problem, as described here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4384f8d2-c429-410b-87e4-1e031ddc8167/enumdisplaydevicesenumdisplaymonitorsgetsystemmetricssmcmonitors-does-not-work-from-a-service?forum=vcgeneral. Thanks though!